# Casting with NewInstance

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I need to make cast from one type to another. Googled but stucked. Say I want to cast `initObject` to `Casted` class.

```
Object objInstance = initObject.getClass().newInstance();
                    Casted str=(Casted)objInstance;
```

Why it make `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Well, what's the actual class of `initObject`, and does it extend `Casted`?

Comment: No, it does not. The task is to make cast from any given type to another given type. Maybe I need to create dynamically class that extends class of object I want to cast?

Comment: I don't think you understand what "cast" means at the moment. Also, note that this doesn't try to cast `initObject` anyway - it creates a new instance of the type of object that the value of `initObject` refers to...

Comment: It's simply impossible in Java to cast from class A to class B unless A extends B. Or from class A to interface B unless A implements B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting requires that Class `Casted` must be a subclass or subinterface of Class `initObject`. For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> castedList = (ArrayList<String>) list; //works
Integer int = (Integer) list; // throws ClassCastException
```

An alternative to casting could be a helper method that will convert related objects. Such an example is the [Collections.toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) method.

Casting is usually discouraged as you are basically telling the compiler that you know what type the casted object is, and of course you could be wrong.

Comment: No problem. You could also accept my answer if you are satisfied with it